# repeated JS alert in livetable php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I've an issue in a project, then:

I've a code php that generates a live table with mysql data. In the right side I've a button that execute a php script to send an email to the address written in corresponding row in the table.
If the result of my search has more than 1 row, it shows the rows, but if I click the button corresponding to the person I want to send the email, a js script showing an alert (correct) for each person shown in the table

here the php code:

```
$output = '';

if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM mytable 
    WHERE Last_Name LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR First_Name LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR Number LIKE '%".$search."%' 
    OR Gmail LIKE '%".$search."%' 
    OR Year LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR Class LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR Password LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR School LIKE '%".$search."%'
    ORDER BY Last_Name LIMIT 200";
}
else
{
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY Last_Name limit 0";
}

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $output .= '<div class="table-responsive well-lg">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center">Last Name</th>
                            <th class="text-center">First Name</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Student Nr.</th>
                            <th class="text-center">School Email</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Year</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Class</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Password</th>
                            <!--<th class="text-center">Doc.</th>-->
                            <th class="text-center">E-Mail</th>


                        </tr>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $output .= '
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">'.utf8_encode($row["Last_Name"]).'</td>
                <td class="text-center">'.utf8_encode($row["First_Name"]).'</td>
                <td class="text-center">'.utf8_encode($row["Number"]).'</td>
                <td class="text-center">'.utf8_encode($row["Gmail"]).'</td>
                <td class="text-center">'.utf8_encode($row["Year"]).'</td>
                <td class="text-center">'.utf8_encode($row["Class"]).'</td>
                <td class="text-center">'.utf8_encode($row["Password"]).'</td>



                <!--<td class="text-center" style="width: 60px"><a href="document.php?firstname='.utf8_encode($row["First_Name"]).'&amp;lastname='.utf8_encode($row["Last_Name"]).'&amp;number='.$row["Number"].'&amp;gmail='.$row["Gmail"].'&amp;password='.$row["Password"].'"><img src="images/document.png" width=18px"></a>
                </td>-->
                <td class="text-center" style="width: 60px">
<a class="ajax confirmation" href="mail_'.$row["School"].'.php?firstname='.utf8_encode($row["First_Name"]).'&amp;lastname='.utf8_encode($row["Last_Name"]).'&amp;number='.$row["Number"].'&amp;gmail='.$row["Gmail"].'&amp;password='.$row["Password"].'"><img src="images/gmail_icon.png" width=24px"></a>
                </td>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(\'.confirmation\').on(\'click\', function () {
        return confirm(\'You are sending the password to ' .$row["Gmail"]. '. Are you sure?\');
    });
</script>






            </tr>


        ';
    }
    echo $output;
```

the js that manage the output in livetable:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_data();
    function load_data(query)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{query:query},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
        var search = $(this).val();
        if(search != '')
        {
            load_data(search);
        }
        else
        {
            load_data();            
        }
    });
```

and this is the code that manage the alert:

```
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".ajax", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType : "html",
            url: href,
            success: function (data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

How can I avoid to show the alert each row shown and permit to show the alert only for the row I clicked?

Please help me...
Thanks for all...
P.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Pablo and welcome to Stack Overflow!

**Updated answer:**

Just found the error in your code:

```php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $output .= '
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(\'.confirmation\').on(\'click\', function () {
        return confirm(\'You are sending the password to ' .$row["Gmail"]. '. Are you sure?\');
      });
    </script>
    ...
'
}
```

You define this inside a loop and therefor create multiple event listeners (in your test 2 entries created 2 listeners). The mail address shown in the popup is based on the current `$row['Gmail']` entry, that's why you see two different mail addresses. The position of the script block was also invalid as it currently is between the closing `</td>` and closing `</tr>` tags.

Modify the code to have one listener and provide the mail address shown in the confirmation dialog as a *"data-"* attribute.

**Changed PHP code:**

```php
<td class="text-center" style="width: 60px">
  <a class="ajax confirmation" 
    data-mail='.$row["Gmail"].' 
    href="mail_'.$row["School"].'.php?firstname='.utf8_encode($row["First_Name"]).'&amp;lastname='.utf8_encode($row["Last_Name"]).'&amp;number='.$row["Number"].'&amp;gmail='.$row["Gmail"].'&amp;password='
    .$row["Password"].'">
    <img src="images/gmail_icon.png" width=24px">
  </a>
</td>
```

**JS code:**

Remove the existing listener defined in the loop completely. This listener will be managing your alerts:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".confirmation", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var mail= $(this).data("mail");
    if (confirm("You are sending the password to " + mail +". Are you sure?")) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType : "html",
            url: href,
            success: function (data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });

    }
});
```

**Update 2:**

As you pointed out there is something causing a loop in your code that keeps showing the confirmation. I don't see what may cause this but here's another alternative that should be foolproof:

**In your PHP**, change it to:

```
<td class="text-center" style="width: 60px">
  <a onclick="sendMail(\''.$row["Gmail"].'\',\'mail_'.$row["School"].'.php?firstname='.utf8_encode($row["First_Name"]).'&amp;lastname='.utf8_encode($row["Last_Name"]).'&amp;number='.$row["Number"].
    '&amp;gmail='.$row["Gmail"].'&amp;password='.$row["Password"].'\')">
    <img src="images/gmail_icon.png" width="24px">
  </a>
</td>
```

Along with this **JS function**:

```js
function sendMail(mail, href)
{
    if (confirm("You are sending the password to " + mail +". Are you sure?")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType : "html",
            url: href,
            success: function (data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your help, now the result is:
if I have 2 results with different mail, and I want to send only to 1 (that I clicked), I have twice the message "are you sure?" for both addresses, I have twice the message "message has been sent to.... (the address I clicked)", then I have to the correct address 2 mails :-(

Comment: @PabloG. the problem was caused due to defining event listeners in a loop. Have a look at my updated answer above, please.

Comment: Woow, seems to work now! thanks so much SaschaM78
have a good day

Comment: sorry, there is the issue...
when I load the page the first time, all sounds good
if I reload the page, i search for something, and try to send, the system goes in loop and propose the same alert....

You are sending the password to.....

and every time I click OK it sends a mail

Comment: @PabloG. If the above code creates a loop, there must be some other code (possibly remainders of your previous code) causing it. You did not include the script as part of your returned AJAX response, right? I added another method in my answer that uses direct function calls rather than using a delegated event listener.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have same class `.ajax` and every class has an `href` attribute. So if there are 20 raw `.ajax` will hit 20 times. So make some difference to get exact result. I am using function for this. Try the below code and revert me if this not work.

```
<td class="text-center" style="width: 60px">
<a class="ajax confirmation" href="mail_'.$row["School"].'.php?firstname='.utf8_encode($row["First_Name"]).'&amp;lastname='.utf8_encode($row["Last_Name"]).'&amp;number='.$row["Number"].'&amp;gmail='.$row["Gmail"].'&amp;password='.$row["Password"].'"><img src="images/gmail_icon.png" width=24px" onClick="buttonClick(this.href)"></a>
</td>

<script>
buttonClick(href){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType : "html",
        url: href,
        success: function (data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: but here I haven't the function recall inside the class, = plain text in the mail send page, no alert message "are you sure"...

Comment: When you click on a raw buttonClick(this.href) will fire for that raw only. I have used this only for id like buttonClick(this.id). I am not sure this will work for href. This is an easy solution so I prefer to try this if this will not work then I will provide other one

Comment: And this is the third time when some one update his answer by follow my code after  seeing my answer

Comment: Dear Yogendra, your solution doesn't change the result, always the loop